# How to change the font appearance of Android Studio terminal to normal state

Tags: android-studio, terminal

The font appearance of my Android Studio terminal looks weird like in SBC mode, how do I change it to normal state?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to `File --> Settings` under `Editor --> Font`, you can change IDE font or select `Color scheme --> console Font` for changing terminal font.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- File -> Settings
- Editor -> Font
  then select
- Color scheme -> console Font